# Why we are getting bad hint error on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We are getting the error as follows:

```
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.571 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.571 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.570 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.570 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.569 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.568 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.568 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.567 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.566 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.566 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.565 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:12:17.565 [conn4498842] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.796 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.795 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.795 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.794 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.793 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.793 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.792 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
Tue Mar 31 22:02:09.791 [conn4504767] assertion 10113 bad hint ns:bp_prod079.BPNote query:{ $query: { admission: ObjectId('54c1ef1b241c90eb1a8b457a') }, $hint: true }
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? Can you paste some code pls?

Comment: Application is running and we are getting this error on database. I don't know which part of application is doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> bad hint ns:bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo query:{ $query: { ip: "10.10.11.28" }, $hint: true }

It looks like, somewhere in your code, you're querying the `bp_prod079.ECLoginInfo` collection like

```
use EBLoginInfo
db.ECLoginInfo.find({ "ip" : "10.10.11.28" }).hint(true)
```

which means somebody doesn't know what [`$hint`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) does. `$hint` expects you to give an index name or specification for the query, e.g.

```
db.ECLoginInfo.find({ "ip" : "10.10.11.28" }).hint({ "ip" : 1 })
```

You need to find where in your code `$hint` is being used incorrectly and either fix the hint or get rid of it. There should be no need for a hint on such simple queries.